# How to remove noise in speakers?

Tags: audio, power-management, tee, runit

After my operating system boots, I can hear repeatedly scratch-like noise from speakers. I googled this problem, and almost found solutions somewhere: if I type like a

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

in terminal, then type a password, this command echoes "0" and noise dissipates. Solution is deficient since its annoying to type the same command every time when booting. Then I have couple more questions:

1. Should I create a new command somewhere in startup scripts to get rid of scratch? Somewhy I wonder if its a good idea, but if so, is [this page](https://voidlinux.org/usage/runit/#service-status) what needs to be followed? I dont have systemd, but runit.
2. What does "echo" do in this bash command? When reading "man echo" I knew only, its needed for variables output etc.

P.S. I have Cinnamon DE, if it does matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The echo command outputs its command line arguments to `stdout`, in this case it's piped as input to the following tee command which runs as root (via sudo) and puts the `0` into the file `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save`.

From [Linux Mint Forums: Frequent loud click sound from audio power save](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=186531):

The best advice is to add

```
options snd_hda_intel power_save=0
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf`.